# Make a div scale up properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my website mobile friendly. Currently, when I use my custom select elements it looks like this:

[image]

Everything looks fine to me, except I want the menu to be bigger on smaller screens. To do this, I tried adding scale: 125% to my containers that hold the Select element:

[image]

It's like the parent elements aren't treating the div as it's new size. I'm not sure what the issue is, because if you look at the tree structure, it starts breaking out of the parent div:

[image]

Even though the CSS is designed to scale to the height of it's content:

```
    .scale-menu__row {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: flex-start;
    min-height: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
}

.scale-menu__row__JCheckboxContainer {
    scale: 150%;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.scale-menu__row__JSelectContainer-scale {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    scale: 150%;
}
.scale-menu__row__JSelectContainer-mode {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    scale: 150%;

}

    .JForm__menustyle {
    height: min-content;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease, max-height 0.5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;

}
```

I tried adding the scale to the JForm__Menustyle class instead- same result. How do I scale up the button while keeping the animation consistent (so that the top doesn't slide up and it doesn't break boundaries)?

Note: I am using React for this project. I'm trying to keep as much CSS in stylesheets as possible. The only inline thing happening here is the div-height for JForm_menustyle changes when clicked.

CodeSandbox: https://0p2x5o.csb.app/

*The relevant CSS is found in App_Mobile.css and JForm.css.
The issue is only shown when viewing in mobile, so shrink down the browser window*

Comment: Have you tried looking into the flex-grow property ?

Comment: What you try to do is called Accordion. HTML has a tag for that: `<details>` and `<summary>`. Try using the correct tags for it instead of trying to reproduce the feature and you can skip most of your CSS and your issue are properly already resolved.

Comment: Can u share a sandbox for your code?

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi I'm using react for this code, so using sandbox would be difficult. I'll try to make a mock-up and see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: just type `react.new` in the browser and paste your code there

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi That's awesome! I added it, see edits